# Using CLASSIC ASP to return data to jsonp call

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, jsonp

I have been through the posts on stackoverflow and cannot seems to find what I am looking for.

If I do (Form:

```
$.ajaxSettings.dataType    = "jsonp";
$.get('http://MYREMOTESERVER.com/GetCustNewID.asp?callback=?', function() {
     //SOMETHING HERE
     });
```

On The remote CLASSIC ASP server how, using asp, would I return the id?

This `Response.Write "[{""id"": " & Rs("@ID") & "}]"` obviously does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried writing something in the ASP page? If yes, what have you written?

Comment: Response.Write "[{""id"": " & Rs("@ID") & "}]"

Comment: what do you mean "does not work" is there an error message ? why is there an "@" symbol in the recordset item ?

Comment: The @ is an OUT parametre returned from a stored procedure. When I run it manually the page displays: [{"id": "25"}] Which shows that it works. But it is just not getting returned via ajax.

Comment: If you are getting the correct value returned in the recordset then the problem is not ASP it is AJAX.  I suggest using examples from library like jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want to know. The Answer is here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/classic-asp-and-jsonp-output

Comment: Please summarize the linked text in your answer. If the link breaks, this answer will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct way to return jsonp using classic asp. We are not returning json, we are returning json wrapped in a javascript callback function so our response is javascript not json.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/javascript"

dim callback
callback = Request("callback") // callback querystring contains the callback function name

Response.Write(callback & "({""result"": ""Done""})")
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with cross-domain ajax depending on browser and/or server settings.  I would make sure this is not the issue.

Comment: Nope. The asp does what it needs to but I am not getting the the id returned. Thanks though.